# Against the Grain, Salt to the Sea: Sudoku

Tags: no-computers, sudoku

> *Against the Grain, Grain of Salt, Salt to the Sea, Sea...badge? What Badge?*

[image]

---

<sup>*Of course, guessing is not fun, right? Anyway, congratulations to anyone who get this! :D*</sup>

Comment: It's rot13(trarenyvfg), of course :P

Comment: Congrats on getting the 201 :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution. I guess it would have been easier if I converted it to numbers, but it was fun to solve as is.

> [image: Solution]

Comment: For completeness, the final solution is found by the other grey patch, rot13(trarenyvfg), which is a reference to [this](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6657/generalist-countdown-one).